# Android. Invisible Top Bar

Tags: android, android-studio

Upd. Problem is solved
I have a problem with app layout: when app is running appears invisible top bar that take the place and shifts elements down. Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBxTW.jpg In the 'Design' window I don't see it and 'Info' button is located in the top of layout. Why this is happening?

Comment: Post your layout

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Done

Comment: Hey, the answer could lie in your manifest and/or styles.xml. Could you paste those as well?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/88wd19F2

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your LinerarLayout ("@+id/linearLayout")

```
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Comment: Removing didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not here. You need to search problem in root layout. If you use android:fitsSystemWindows="true",  you need to remove it. Maybe, do you use coordinatorlayout?

> android:fitsSystemWindows="true"  //remove the line

Comment: No, I don't use coordinatorlayout. And I cannot find `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` Maybe this is related to the fact that I am using bottom nav bar?

Comment: can you share source the screen?

Comment: Thank you. Problem is solved, this was extra padding.